# How to load two images in a View in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, cocoa

i am a newbie to objective c and Xcode. I found this code that allows me to load an image into my device from an url and replace it to one i have in the View associated to the class containing this code.. Now i need to load TWO image in the same class, to replace two image that are in the same View... How can i?

EDIT: To be clear: i have a view containing two image view. Each image view display an image contained in a file having a specific name contained in the app resources. Say the first image view contains "image1.jpg" and the second "image2.jpg". What i am trying to do is replace into the device the two image "image1.jpg" and "image2.jpg" with two images taken from the web (for the sake of an update of some app images to be done eventually during the app life trought the use of an xml, and so on).

```
- (void)loadImgFromURLString: (NSString *)theUrlString{
    NSLog(@"Downloading image...");
    backgroundHome.image = nil;    

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:theUrlString]
                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                        timeoutInterval:30.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
              initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection
     didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {
    if (data == nil)
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];

    [data appendData:incrementalData];
 }

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection{
    backgroundHome.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    NSLog(@"Image ready...");

    // save image in document dir
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.png",docDir];
    [data writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: akv why you commented the two function?

Comment: those two fuctions are only for  gettng string...

Comment: SO you need to replace two existing images with new one?

Comment: getting string? can you explain me?

Comment: Sorry,, getting image from url.

Comment: yes, exactly! Sorry if i wasn't clear before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a second image to your view is not the real problem I suppose?

Your callenge is to assign the loaded data to the appropriate image if there are more than one.

You could add this code to a subclass of UIImageView. Doing so each UIImageView would create its own request and receive its own image data. Eventually you assign it to self.image = ...

That is what I would do.

Alternative: 
You create an image loader class that has a reference to the UIImageView. Of these you create two instances. Each of the instances 'knows' its very own UIImageView and issues a request and eventually saves the image data to its own UIImageView.

Next Alternative (I never tried that)

```
NSMutableDictionary ongoingRequests = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

- (void)loadImgFromURLString: (NSString *)theUrlString forImageView:(UIImageView)theView {
    backgroundHome.image = nil;    

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:theUrlString]
                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                        timeoutInterval:30.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
              initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [self.ongoingRequests setObject:theView forKey:connection]
 }

[...]

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection{
    UIImageView *theView = [self.ongoingRequests objectWithKey:theConnection]
    theView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    self.ongoingRequests removeObjectForKey:theConnection;

    // save image in document dir
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.png",docDir];
[data writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: i'm guessing AKV is trying to tell me the same thing, but i can't get it.. I've always associated a class to one... how can i refer it to, screen (or frame? i mean one single frame of the storyboard, you know?) of the app which have inside his iboutlet representing imageview and so on... So, you are telling me i can associate a new class to an image view that is inside a frame of the app? How can i?

Comment: Yes of course. Just subclass UIImageView. Then add an UIImageView in IB. (You probably have them there already) Then change the class in IB to your subclass. However, if you do not want to subclass UIImageView then you can extend it. If you even do not want to extend it then I have provided two alternatives that go without mainpulating the UIImageView itself.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Which of the alternatives did you choose?

Comment: Shame on myself, i solved the problem with a terrible workout: at the end of the first cycle of the three function i made the function to be repeated one more time with different data using,as way to repeat, a bool global variable... I was such in a hurry! But i'm still trying to have things go in the right way,that i still think is yours. I tried to create two classes to manipulate the two image view of the two images but i couldn't still find the right code to made the loading be executed when the main view appear... The way of the force is still long for this young Xcode padawan!

Comment: All right. Yes, serializing the requrests is certainly an option. I did that myself once for the same resouces. At that time I too needed a quick solution and used this workaround. My app crashed when a view controller requested a resouce (a jpeg image) while an older request for the same image was still ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

Create two subviews inside your main view.

Load images on them, and manipulate as you want.

This will be easier for you.

Comment: i have two subviews, but i have no idea how to do the rest ^^'

Comment: specifically in the passage trougth the three function loadImgFromURLString - connection - connectionDidFinishLoading i lose control of who is been loaded. Imagine i've been executing the function loadImgFromURLString two times with two different url... Arrived to the end of the connectionDidFinishLoading how i can fill the name of the file in the line [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.png",docDir]? At that point i don't now which of the two function is executing the connectionDidFinishLoading. I hope you you get what is my problem...